# Batch scripting: Why does this print "= instead of the empty string?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

I'm trying to remove quotes in some text using parameter expansion in Batch. Can anyone tell me why this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set args=%*
echo %args:"=%
```

prints `"=` instead of nothing? As far as I can see `%args:"=%` should replace all quotes with nothing, so I don't get why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**edit:** To clarify, I'm not passing any parameters to the batch script.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It works in my PC, unless no parameter is passed

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I'm not passing any parameters to the script, either. Perhaps that's part of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the result you get when you do not pass any arguments to your script.

If `args` is not defined, then `%args:"=%` is expanded as follows:

- `%args:` is treated as a non existent variable expansion, which becomes nothing
- `"=` is treated as itself
- `%` (a lone percent) is stripped

It is not intuitive, but that happens to be how cmd.exe works. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/1012053 for more info.

You can prevent the problem by using `if defined`

```
@echo off
setlocal

set args=%*
if defined args echo %args:"=%
```

Comment: Very neat explanation. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

It works here

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2.bat" dog
dog
```

Removing echo off shows this

```
C:\Windows\system32>setlocal

C:\Windows\system32>set args=dog

C:\Windows\system32>echo dog
dog
```

You are not passing any command line arguments.

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test2.bat"

C:\Windows\system32>setlocal

C:\Windows\system32>set args=

C:\Windows\system32>echo "=
"=
```

Comment: the parameters in your example don't have any quotes

Comment: I duplicated his symptoms.